# Switching from Arco Linux to Ubuntu

Tags: apt, package-management

I recently switched from Arco Linux (Arch-Based Distro) to Ubuntu, I have a 'packages.txt' for my Arch install but now I want to switch Ubuntu and I want to use all of my programs which I had installed on Arch but my 'packages.txt' has all Arch packages name. How do I make it so all the same programs are installed. My 'packages.txt' is hosted on my github. "https://github.com/adamkagdi/allpackages".

Answer (score 0):

Arch and Ubuntu are very different distributions, relying on totally independent package managers. Package names may therefore be different. You will have to go through your packages.txt file and change Arch packages to "equivalent" Ubuntu packages. Unless someone already scripted this, that will be a manual job.

Better yet: just take a little time to adapt your system while you are working with it. When it is tweaked the way you want, you can retrieve a list of installed ubuntu packages for future reference.

Comment: Is there a way that a program can just change the names from Arch or AUR to Apt??

Comment: No: 1) No program can guess how a package is named in Ubuntu and in Arch, and 2) There is not necessarily 1:1 overlap, i.e., something you install with two packages in Arch may be installed with  one package in Ubuntu or vice versa. You could start start writing a program yourself, but then, it would need constant updating.